# Getting a num_rows total to echo each number up to its total in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have the following prepared statement that I created in an attempt to get the number of rows in my database for the posts that are affiliated with a topic. So basically what I am trying to do is similar to if you were on a forum and each time someone posts a reply to a topic, you will see a post number in your reply.

This is my prepared statement in which I am echoing out the number of rows in the current topic and it is coming up correctly.

```
if ($posts_stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `id`=?")) {

    $posts_stmt->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
    $posts_stmt->execute();
}   

    $posts_stmt->store_result();
    $post_num_rows = $posts_stmt->num_rows;
    echo "Number of rows" . $post_num_rows;
```

However, I can't figure out how to display each number per reply in the reply boxes.

ie:

If there are 5 total rows, there will be five different replies or reply boxes. I can't figure out how to make the reply boxes do this..

1

2

3

4

5

I echo out some of the post's information like this and this is where I do not know how to structure the code to do as I am wanting.

```
echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
    <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$topic_title."<br />
    by ".$post_creator." - " .$post_date. "<hr />" . $post_content ."</div></td>
   <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

UPDATE - my fetch

```
$posts_stmt->store_result();
    while ($row_count = $posts_stmt->fetch()) {
    $post_num_rows = $posts_stmt->num_rows;
    echo "Number of rows" . $post_num_rows;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to fetch rows from the result object `$posts_stmt`.

Comment: I actually didn't have one, but I just made one really quickly and I am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a counter in the loop while you are using `fetch_row()`. You initialize the counter to 0 and increment it in the loop

Also, if you are using PDO. You don't need to use `store_result`

```
  if ($posts_stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE 
      `category_id`=? AND `id`=?")) {
     $posts_stmt->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
     $posts_stmt->execute();
}   

$rows = $posts_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //now run through all the data with a while loop
    //the count will have the correct 1,2,3,4.. values
    $count=0;
    foreach($rows as $row) {
       $count++;
       echo $count. " ".$row['post_title'] ; // and other echo stuff
    }
```

---

**EDITS**

1. Rather than editing that bit of code I thought I would re-write the answer.
   First rather than use `mysqli` it is recommended to use PDO. Which is the new PHP way to access databases. Its similar to MySQL but has a few new methods and is just all in all better.
2. How to get all your rows in `MySQLi`

Don't use `store_result` unless you have to. And it doesn't seem like you do so just do this instead after the execute

```
    $result = $posts_stmt->get_result();
    $count=0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $count++;
        echo $count." ".$row['post_title'];
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do I still have to have my num_rows code in side of that loop? I'm getting errors for it.. `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object` Then I am getting an error for an undefined variable for `$result`...What does $result have to be? What are you meaning that to be?

Comment: Sorry. I typed `$result` wrong. It was meant to be `$data`. I have corrected it above

Comment: Any idea why this is coming up? `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on`

Comment: I just updated the code to the recommended code from php docs. Could you tell me if its running?

Comment: No, still getting this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object`

Comment: Okay. I changed the answer a lot. Try it now

Comment: Another error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll()`

Comment: If I t change the fetchAll to just fetch, I get these errors.. `Fatal error: Call to a member function store_result() on a non-object`  and `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and `Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given i`

Comment: Done a rather large update. If you still have problems, I suggest we continue this in the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84193/discussion-between-cjds-and-paul).